# jQuery 'change' method (for HTML attribute modify) working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this pair of functions affecting two inputs, and one select. These are exclusive so when inputs are filled, select must be modified to have option 3 selected, and when any option except 3 is selected, both inputs must be empty:

```
$('#ar_filter').on('change', '#ar_fromDate, #ar_toDate', function() {
        if ($('#ar_fromDate, #ar_toDate').val!=""){
           $('.lastDays').attr('readonly','readonly').find('option[value=3]').attr('selected', true);
        }
    });   

$('#ar_filter').on('change', '#lastDays', 'select', function() {
        if ($('.lastDays').val()!=3){
            $('#ar_fromDate, #ar_toDate').val("");
        }
    });
```

This works, but only the first time. When I write some value on the inputs, it resets correctly select to value 3, but when I change manually selected options, after it resets and leaves inputs empty, it does not reset anymore the select, even when writing on any of those inputs.

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4430/)** (try making 2 select resets by filling the inputs: it will only make the first one)

Comment: Are you really intending `select` to be passed to the handler as _data_ in your second [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) binding or are you wanting it to be part of the selector? I think you're selector is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure if I understoiod your question. I want #lastDays select to be the selector for this, executing the actions every time an option from #lastDays is selected

Comment: Check my answer below, I think that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your JSFiddle, I believe your second implementation of `.on()` is incorrect. The third optional argument can be passed as *data* to the handler function as denoted in the [reference documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try changing:

```
$('#ar_filter').on('change', '#lastDays', 'select', function() {
```

to this:

```
$('#ar_filter').on('change', '#lastDays', function() {
```

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249465/jquery-change-method-for-html-attribute-modify-working-only-once/24249577#comment-37456622) above, I believe your selector is wrong. `#lastDays` is the `id` of the `<select>` element, which is where you want the `change` event bound. The extra `select` is not needed.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4433/)

**Note:**

The updated fiddle includes the `.val()` fix described by *@tymeJV* in his answer.

**EDIT:**

In addition to the `.on()` selector fix described above, you'll need to break out the two selectors in your [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) statement. This is because only the first input will be validated each time the change event occurs. This comes directly from the jQuery documentation for `.val()`:

> Get the current value of the **first** element in the set of matched elements.

The second value will not be fetched or validated.

Change this:

```
$('#ar_fromDate, #ar_toDate').val() != ""
```

to this:

```
$('#ar_fromDate').val() != "" || $('#ar_toDate').val() != ""
```

This should fix the problem. I've included an updated fiddle below. I've left the original fiddle in tact to show the progression of steps in solving this problem for the benefit of future visitors.

[**Complete Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4434/)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. After changing the .on following your instruction,s problem persists. Here you have the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4432/

Comment: On your updated fiddle you can see how problem persists: just reset once the select by typing anything on the inputs, then select manually any non-3-value option and then type again: it won't reset select

Comment: @Biomehanika It appears to work fine. When changing one of your `<input />`'s the select changes to option 3. When the `<select>` changes, the `<input />`'s are cleared. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But if AFTER THAT you type anyrthing on the inputs, it does not turn AGAIN seletc to value 3. I expect select to change to value 3 every time user types anything on inputs, not just the first time.. cant you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle? I can

Comment: The problem is your use of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Per the documentation `.val()`: _"Get the current value of the **first** element in the set of matched elements."_. This is where I got confused as well. The code provided works perfectly with the first input but not with the second. You need to separate out the two selectors so that both are validated. I've provided an edited fix in my answer above.

Comment: I am very grateful for your effort. Eventhow, I have opened COMPLETE FIDDLE link and the problem persist: type something, then change selection, then type something: selection does not change. Is http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/4434/ correct link?

Comment: @Biomehanika No problem buddy. Glad to help. That's strange that it's not working though. It's working every time for me. Two questions: (1) What browser are you using? (2) What are you typing as your input values?

Comment: I am using last Firefox version, and I use to type a "1", I'0ve also tried with text and it happens the same

Comment: @Biomehanika I think that may be the problem. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=input-date), Firefox does not yet fully support the `type="date"` input. Chrome supports the majority of the spec which is what I was testing in. You can confirm this by opening the fiddle in Chrome and in Firefox. In Chrome, there is a little black arrow that displays a popup calendar widget. This is missing in Firefox. [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-browser-datepickers-within-minutes--net-20236) site has a polyfill that should work across browsers.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort. At least I solved thgis with a mouseup event, which gets to the same objective. The fact is that even when Firefox does not fully support date inputs, class "datyepicker" is there because launches a light calendar pluguin that solves this. In any case, I am very grateful for your help.